# locust stat for single api call

Tags: python, api, load-testing, locust

in the [locust documentation](https://docs.locust.io/en/stable/running-without-web-ui.html#controlling-the-exit-code-of-the-locust-process) is specified how to get aggregated stats. However both the csv you can generate and in the web UI you have stats divided per api call.

My use case: Just like in the documentation example I linked above, but I want to exit with status 1 when a single API call has a fail ration above 0.01.
I do not want to fail when `environment.stats.total.fail_ratio > 0.01` but when `environment.stats.my_single_api_call.fail_ratio > 0.01`

Moreover since I can see I have a lot of single requests in the form

```
/api/application/v1/action/param1/report
/api/application/v1/action/param2/report
/api/application/v1/action/param3/report
```

it would be great if I could loop the request's and aggregate the same one that have different parameters

Comment: I’m on mobile right now so I cant find the exact place, but try running in the debugger and examine the environment.stats object. https://docs.locust.io/en/stable/running-in-debugger.html

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can get stats by request name+method by using the `RequestStats.get`-method, e.g.

```
environment.stats.get("/api/application/v1/action/param1/report", "GET")
```